# How to calculate sha1 base64 encoded in windows batch?

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, openssl, command

I am trying to get a base64 encoded sha1 hash in a windows batch file.
The first thing I tried was with perl:

```
perl -M"Digest::SHA1 qw(sha1_base64)" -e "open(F,shift) or die; binmode F; print sha1_base64(<F>), qq(=\n)" "test.mxf"
```

This works great, but only for small files. With big files it says "Out of memory".

Then I downloaded an openssl version for windows and tried this:

```
"C:\openssl.exe" dgst -sha1 -binary -out "hash_sha1.txt" "C:\test.mxf"
set /p hash_sha1=<"hash_sha1.txt"
del "hash_sha1.txt"
echo !hash_sha1!

echo -n '!hash_sha1!' | "C:\openssl.exe" enc -base64
```

But the output of the openssl method is different from the Perl output and I know that the Perl method produces the correct output. What do I have to change?

Comment: Tip: `-M"Digest::SHA1 qw(sha1_base64)"` can be shortened to `-MDigest::SHA1=sha1_base64`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There's no `-n` parameter of `echo` so `-n` AND single quotes are part of the output.
- The intermediate files and variables aren't needed, use piping.

The entire code:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -binary "C:\test.mxf" | openssl enc -base64
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create a `Digest::SHA1` object, you can use the `add` method to calculate the hash incrementally

There is also no need to explicitly open files passed as command-line parameters. They are opened automatically using the built-in file handle `ARGV`, and can be read with the empoty diamond operator `<>`

```
perl -Mopen=IN,:raw -MDigest::SHA1 -e"$d=Digest::SHA1->new; $d->add($_) while <>; print $d->b64digest, qq{=\n}" 5GB.bin
```

This command line was quite happy to generate the SHA1 hash of a 5GB file, but if you are unlucky enough to have a very big file that contains no linefeeds then you will have to set a read block size with something like

```
local $/ = \(1024*1024)
```